# Find Index of Object in array with Aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to get index in aggregate pipeline, I have a result from long aggreagte query

```
[
    {
        "_id": "59ed949227ec482044b2671e",
        "points": 300,
        "fan_detail": [
            {
                "_id": "59ed949227ec482044b2671e",
                "name": "mila   ",
                "email": "mila@gmail.com ",
                "password": "$2a$10$J0.KfwVnZkaimxj/BiqGW.D40qXhvrDA952VV8x.xdefjNADaxnSW",
                "username": "mila  0321",
                "updated_at": "2017-10-23T07:04:50.004Z",
                "created_at": "2017-10-23T07:04:50.004Z",
                "celebrity_request_status": 0,
                "push_notification": [],
                "fan_array": [],
                "fanLength": 0,
                "celeb_bio": null,
                "is_admin": 0,
                "is_blocked": 2,
                "notification_setting": [
                    1,
                    2,
                    3,
                    4,
                    5,
                    6,
                    7
                ],
                "total_stars": 0,
                "total_points": 134800,
                "user_type": 2,
                "poster_pic": null,
                "profile_pic": "1508742289662.jpg",
                "facebook_id": "alistnvU79vcc81PLW9o",
                "is_user_active": 1,
                "is_username_selected": "false",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

so I want to find the index of `_id` in aggregate query and above array can contain 100s of object in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the available version of MongoDB you have there are different approaches:

### `$indexOfArray` - MongoDB 3.4

The best operator for this is simply [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) where you have it available. The name says it all really:

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "fan_detail._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("59ed949227ec482044b2671e") } },

  { "$addFields": { 
    "fanIndex": {
      "$indexOfArray": [
        "$fan_detail._id",
        mongoose.Types.ObjectId("59ed949227ec482044b2671e")
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

### `$unwind` with `includeArrayIndex` - MongoDB 3.2

Going back a version in releases, you can get the index from the array from the syntax of [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). But this does require you to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array:

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "fan_detail._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("59ed949227ec482044b2671e") } },
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$fan_detail", "includeArrayIndex": true } },
  { "$match": { "fan_detail._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("59ed949227ec482044b2671e") } }
])
```

### mapReduce - Earlier versions

Earlier versions of MongoDB to 3.2 don't have a way of returning an array index in an aggregation pipeline. So if you want the matched index instead of all the data, then you use [`mapReduce`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.mapReduce) instead:

```
Model.mapReduce({
  map: function() {
    emit(
      this._id,
      this['fan_detail']
        .map( f => f._id.valueOf() )
        .indexOf("59ed949227ec482044b2671e") 
    )
  },
  reduce: function() {},
  query: { "fan_detail._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("59ed949227ec482044b2671e") }
})
```

In all cases we essentially "query" for the presence of the element "somewhere" in the array beforehand. The "indexOf" variants would return `-1` where nothing was found otherwise.

Also [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) is here just for example. If it's your real intent to not return the array of 100's of items, then you're probably using [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) or other output anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and its correct yeah I am using pagination as well to limit the 100s records

Comment: @IrfanKhan Well there is also [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) if you were just simply looking to do that. "Pagination of arrays" is why that has been around since very early releases of MongoDB.